# database not being updated

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble with this php page, for some reason when i run it the query is not executed

```
<html>
<?php   
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
if (!$link) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

    for($i = 0; $i<$_GET['count'];$i++)
    {
     $query ="UPDATE `TEST.table` SET `Lan_ID` = '".$_GET[$i.'LanID'].
             "', `Switching` = '".$_GET[$i.'Switching'].
             "',`Own` = '".$_GET[$i.'Own'].
             "',`Division` = '".$_GET[$i.'Division'].
             "',`Switch_Number` = '".$_GET[$i.'Switch_Number'].
             "', `Telecom_Circuit_number` = '".$_GET    [$i.'Telecom_Circuit_number'].
             "', `Transmitter_Frequency` = '".$_GET[$i.'Trasmitter_frq'].
             "', `Receiver_Frequency` = '".$_GET[$i.'Receiver_frq'].
             "',    `Band_width` = '".$_GET[$i.'Band_width'].
             "', `Channel` = '".$_GET[$i.'Channel'].
             "', `Equipment` = '".$_GET[$i.'Equipment'].
             "', `Power` = '".$_GET[$i.'Power'].
             "', `Line_designation` = '".$_GET[$i.'Line_designation'].
             "', `Voltage` = '".$_GET[$i.'Voltage'].
             "', `Phase` = '".$_GET[$i.'Phase'].
             "', `Modulate` = '".$_GET[$i.'Modulate'].
             "', `Terms` = '".$_GET[$i.'Terms'].
             "', `Trap` = '".$_GET[$i.'Trap'].
             "', `Ltunner` = '".$_GET[$i.'Ltunner'].
             "', `Link` = '".$_GET[$i.'Link'].
             "', `Comment` = '".$_GET[$i.'Comment']."'";
     $query = $query. " " . $_GET['where'.$i];
    mysql_query($query, $link);

    }
    ?>
</html>
```

However, when i run the run the query on MYSQL workbench it does execute and it updates the data, i been trying to figure it out for about an hour and i have not found anything, Thank you for your help

Comment: I am just going to say "learn PDO/Mysqli" and just ... walk away

Comment: This may be today's record for the most SQL injection points in a single line of code.

Comment: Switching to MySQLi or PDO as Simon_eQ suggestions would be a very good idea; and this really ought to be a prepared statement to protected against SQL injection. In spite of all that, mysql_errno and mysql_error might at least tell you why it is failing -- consider checking and displaying the results of those functions.

Comment: This... this... OMG, I don't even know where to begin. However, you are missing, among others, a `" WHERE whateverfield = " . $_GET['where'.$i]`.

Comment: In *addition* to switching to PDO, *deal with the potential SQL errors* - display, log, die, or whatever, but do something besides ignore them. They will say *what* went wrong, or at least give hints as to what the problem was. The given user might not even have UPDATE privileges - although I bet it's just invalid syntax; possibly caused by inadvertent injection.

Comment: Any number of problems here. You are using mysql functions. You shouldnn't You have terrible SQL injection vulnerability. You are accepting a whole `WHERE` clause as a GET parameter. That is just insane. You are also using GET to update you database which is typically a really bad idea (DB's changed should typically be done via POST, so you don't have people updating your DB because they bookmarked you page, or went to it in navigation history). That aside, have you actually compared the query as built with the one you directly in DB? Have you looked at mysql errors to see what problem may be?

Comment: @MikeBrant , I didn't even consider that, I thought he just missed the `WHERE`.

Comment: Please heed the advice above! in the mean time use `echo $query; mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());` and learn to debug.

Comment: well... thank you for destroying my morale... lol... I did not know anything about PDO or Mysqli, I havent taken any mysql classes in school yet, I am going to do more research and learn more. Thank you again

Comment: @user2585242 Don't worry, we have all been there before. Just learn/search about 'PHP Best Practices' or check out some good PHP tutorials starting by understanding what is `Mysql Injection`, why is it bad, and how to avoid it. Eventually, you'll get there. It is just a matter of time, so ... start doing things right from today. If you have any doubts/problems come by to the [**PHP Room**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and ask some questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please heed the advice others have provided.

This is strongly suspect:

```
UPDATE `TEST.table` SET
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Normally, we don't use a period as a character in a table name.

I'm suspicious that what you wanted here was actually the name of a database, and the name of a table. The period delimiter does not get enclosed in the backticks, unless that is actually the name of the table.

```
UPDATE `TEST`.`table` SET
        ^^^^   ^^^^^
```

That's the most likely explanation I can think of as to why you aren't seeing any rows updated in your database table.

The simplest way to debug this type of issue is to print out the actual string that is going to be sent to MySQL, immediately before you send it. (Or, when developing, instead of sending the query)

```
echo $query;
```

Also, best practice is to check whether your execution of the SQL statement threw an error or not, rather than pulling a Dr. Evil shut the door and pinky-to-the-corner-of-the-mouth "I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?"

Again, please heed the advice others have provided. And beware of "Little Bobby Tables".

http://xkcd.com/327/