# why is null inserted in database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I am trying to create a form that user is choosing an option let's say that he will choose his name i used ajax to call another page , in this page i create the connection and inserting the answer the problem it's inserting null 
Code
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MyDataBase </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#mysubmit").click( function (){
    $.ajax({
        url:"Final.php",
        type:"POST",
        success: function(success_array)
        {   
            alert(" Well Done ");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            alert( " Didn't work ! ");
        }
    });
 });
   });

 </script>  
  </head>
  <form method="post" id = "myform">
  <input type="radio" name="kname" value="X1" />X1<br  />
  <input type="radio" name="kname" value="Y1" />Y1<br  />
  <input type="radio" name="kname" value="A1" />A1<br  />
  <input type="radio" name="kname" value="G1" />G1<br  />
  <input type="submit" onclick="save()"  id="mysubmit"/>
  </form>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Final.php

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Thanks</title>
        </head>

        <body>
        <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xyz","test");
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO name values ('$_POST[kname]')");
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White , it's nothing compared with the [question I just visited](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17664993/). Still this is vulnerable to SQL injection and should be fixed.

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerability. So what debugging have you done to try to narrow this down? Have you considered trying to handle MySQL errors to see what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the kname via `$_POST['kname']`.

But please! always escape your values!

Comment: What do u mean by "reference the kname" sorry i am still new bie in this

Comment: You have to use quotes around `kname` because elsewise the compiler would consider `kname` a constant.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting/posting via ajax you need to add your data. simplest is with [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
 var form = $('#myform');
 $.ajax({
    url:"Final.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    ...
```

or you could get a single field -

```
   data: {kname: $('#id_of_your_radio').val()},
```

just make sure to sanitize the userdata before inserting into your db.

Comment: have you checked firebug (firefox) or developer console (chrome, etc) to see what is being posted for `kname`?

Comment: you have `onclick="save()"` in your submit button. Where is `save()` defined? I assume this is unneccessary as you are binding the `$("#mysubmit").click( function (){...});`. Try removing the `onclick="save()"`.